# Inconsistent decoding of encoded URL query parameters using Python and GAE

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, url-encoding

I'm trying to get consistent URL strings in my mobile client before submitting, and on the server once received, to be able to reliably add a hash for security checksum purposes.  Currently I'm adding the hash after URL-encoding on the client, and attempting to grab the URL before anything gets decoded on the server, but I'm getting one character (a period) already decoded:

When I post something like this:

```
 https://myapp.appspot.com/endpt?par=0%3Afirstlast%40gmail%2Ecom&di . . .
```

From this on the server:

```
self.request.url
```

I get:

```
https://myapp.appspot.com/endpt?par=0%3Afirstlast%40gmail.com&di . . .
```

And from this:

```
self.request.get('par')
```

I get it completely decoded as I would expect:

```
0:firstlast@gmail.com
```

I'm wondering how I can grab the URL before ANY decoding happens?  Or alternately, I could do my hashing outside of the encoding/decoding if it's possible to grab the URL with the entire query portion decoded?  I.e. I can inject my hash at any point that I can get consistent, reliable results.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not just fully decode both sides before hashing?

Comment: Thanks @Eli.  The original thought for hashing "inside" any encoding (i.e. after client encoding and before server decoding) was to be immune to any encoding to decoding inconsistency.  But given this issue, I did go ahead and move hashing "outside" of encoding, and while I did end up tweaking the encoding side, all seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch this directly from your WSGI environment, but I'd suggest taking a page out of [Amazon's book](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) instead, and defining a canonical format for signing URLs. Then you can encode and format the URLs in the same way on both ends, and you don't have to rely on the vagaries of frameworks and proxies not to interfere with the trivial encoding details of your URLs.